# WPF ListView in GridView mode Highlighting problem

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, gridview, listview

While reskining GridView (ListView with more columns), I ran into a problem, that I couldn't change the color of the Highlighted row. I searched the internet and found out, that adding this can help.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent" />
```

This solved the issue for some people but it didnt help me. The Highlight color was still in system default. I finally managed to change the color of the selected row, but the highlight is still visible around the border of the row plus i need to get rid of the Highlight in the ColumnHeaders.

Heres the code, where my approach doesn't work:

```
<ListView >
 <ListView.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="Transparent" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                   Color="Transparent" />
 </ListView.Resources>
 <ListView.View>
  <GridView>
   <GridViewColumn Header="a"/>
   <GridViewColumn Header="b"/>
  </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
 <ListViewItem>sth</ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem>sthelse</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score -1):

if I truly understand, you want to remove Highlight color.
if you want to do this, this is simple. Use this style:

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

but for using this style you must use that style for `ItemContainerStyle` property.

I hope this solution help you.

regards Rev

Comment: Added this to the ItemContainerStyle but gridview still resisting. ListView works fine with this change (but even my solution managed to resolve the normal listview). :-(