# Setting the Template Background from style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, styles

I have a style like this

```
<Style x:Key="LeavesStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ListBoxEditItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />//Not Working
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and my `Template`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ListBoxEditItem}">
            <Border x:Name="rootBorder" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="{dxi:ThemeResource ThemeKey={dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=GridDataRowDelimiterBrush}}">
```

How can I access the `rootBorder` from `Background` from style? to set the `rootBorders` `Background`

I know I can do like this 
 `<Setter TargetName="rootBorder" Property="Background" Value="Orange" />`

inside my template, I wanna do this from style Please help stuck here from so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Background` property is not applied automatically to your border. You need to link the borders background to the background property of your control. You can do that using a `TemplateBinding`:

```
 <ControlTemplate>
     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Changing the Background property of the control in your style will now change the background of your item.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to override the controltemplate in style and add the border in it

You can see a similiar solutiom here: [WPF ListView Style Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971771/wpf-listview-style-borders)